# Implementation of Emoticons through library

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, ime

I have found this library for emoticons in android:-
https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

In this, I am having a problem how to combine this code with my android soft keyboard or how do I deploy the emojicons tab on button click.

Note that I don't have any main activity as it is just a keyboard app.

I have almost same code as that of Android Soft Keyboard here:-
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/src/com/example/android/softkeyboard/SoftKeyboard.java

I have to do this just like it is done in Kika Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind any keyboard key with inflation and replacement of a view with emoji pane.
Then send a proper unicode (emoji) to the InputConnection.